# Selenium Webdriver ConnectionAbortedError in case of 5sec sleeps in between commands

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

My Selenium-WebDriver + Python scripts work fine, but give a `ConnectionAbortedError` if there is too much time in between the webdriver commands.

The following minimum working example gives an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
searchfield = browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib") 
time.sleep(5) 
browser.close() # -> ConnectionAbortedError
```

while without the 5 second sleep, there is no error:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
searchfield = browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
browser.close()
```

No one else seems to have had this issue... Is it normal that the connection is lost after several seconds? Or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried to use *implicitly_wait* and *set_script_timeout*, but increasing these timeouts did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ConnectionAbortedError

You are seeing **ConnectionAbortedError** as the default timeout for the **`keep-alive connection`** is **5s**.

As per @andreastt's [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304#issuecomment-399514438) in the discussion [Keep-Alive connection to geckodriver 0.21.0 dropped after 5s of inactivity without re-connection using Selenium Python client](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304) *GekcoDriver v0.21.0* switched on to use **HTTP/1.1 Keep-Alive connections**.

As you mentioned *ConnectionAbortedError if there is 5 second sleep between the webdriver commands* is confirmed by @whimboo's [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304#issuecomment-400229653) where he mentions:

> It looks like the default timeout for the keep-alive connection is 5s. Sadly once this time passed-by the connection is not correctly re-instantiated.

Here is the reference to [**Why 5s?**](https://hyper.rs/hyper/0.8.0/hyper/server/struct.Server.html#method.keep_alive)

*GeckoDriver team* could have to bumped up this timeout to a sane value, but on the other side the client also has to create a new connection in case of failures. The expectation was that the client needs to check whether the connection is still alive before using it. When the connection eventually gets closed by the server after five seconds of inactivity, the client needs to make a new connection. Though it makes much sense to bump up the **Keep-Alive timeout** duration.  Ias it is a common practice for *Automation Testers* to wait **five seconds** for an operation to complete or for a **five second thread sleep** for an element to be present/visible in the tests.

But again, capping the `Keep-Alive connection timeout` to a higher value will not resolve the underlying issue as there are bugs in WebDriver clients’ handling of HTTP connections mentioned in [Support keep alive connections](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1468398).

Further @AutomatedTester mentioned:

> This issue is not because we are not connected at the time of doing a request. If that was the issue we would be getting a `httplib.HTTPConnection` exception being thrown. Instead a `BadStatusLine` is thrown when we do a connection and close it and try parse the response.
>   Now this could be the python stdlib bug, httplib bug or selenium bug, which will need investigating.

@andreastt adds:

> The HTTPD’s `Keep-Alive` timeout value is orthogonal to this issue.  It is a known issue that the Python 2.7 standard library that urllib, used by the Selenium Python client, does not conform to HTTP/1.1. Increasing the server timeout would mitigate this, but not resolve the underlying problem, which is that the HTTP library in Python has a defect.
>
> The issue appears to be fixed in more recent Python versions. When we investigated this we also found that various HTTP libraries built on top of urllib, such as requests, works around the issue using various mechanisms (like special-casing the `BadStatusLine` exception and re-connecting).
>
> *Selenium Team* was working on a patch for the Python client to replace urllib with something else that does not exhibit the same defect with `Keep-Alive` connections. This work can be tracked in [**Urllib3**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6103).
>
> Meanwhile the geckodriver team is working on extending the server-side timeout value to something more reasonable. As I said, this would help mitigate this issue but not fundamentally fix it. In any case it is true that five seconds is probably too low to get real benefit from persistent HTTP connections, and that increasing it to something like 60 seconds would have greater performance.

You can track the work on increasing the server `Keep-Alive` timeout in the discussion [Increase Keep-Alive connection drop timeout](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1471201).

### Solution

Upgrading your *Test Environment* to use **Selenium v3.14.0** may solve your issue.

Comment: I can't because I am a new user of this forum and have too few reputation points.